# toggle attribute in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oauth, boolean

If the user doesn't sign up with twitter or facebook the provider attribute is blank and the user is a pro user. I've added the pro attribute to the database as a boolean and the default is false.

I'm trying to toggle the pro attribute in the database to true using the code below.

```
  def pro?
    toggle!(:pro) if provider.blank? 
  end
```

However I get this error.

```
stack level too deep
```

I also tried 
      def pro?
        :pro => true if provider.blank? 
      end
but get this error:

```
 syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
```

Note I also need to use the pro method because it is used in many other places in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `pro` attribute defined as boolean, the following methods are all available for free:

- `pro?` : returns the boolean value of the `pro` attribute
- `pro=` : sets the value of `pro`

A ruby method ending in a `?` is expected to return a boolean, without any side-effects.

What I would do, in your case, is add a callback:

```
class User

  before_save :check_pro_status

  def check_pro_status
    pro = provider.blank?
  end

end
```

This will make sure that everytime something is changed in your `user`, before saving, it will set the `pro`-status correctly depending on the provider.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you defining boolean column on ActiveRecord database, `:pro` for example, you gain `pro?` method for free. When you overwrite `pro?` this way, it will raise `stack level too deep`. So, consider renaming your method, for example:

```
def toggle_pro?
  toggle!(:pro) if provider.blank? 
end
```

Comment: No luck still returning false. Thanks Denis!

Comment: It is probably `provider.blank?` returns false, check it first.

Comment: Yea by default it should return false as the column pro is a boolean with the default value of false in the database. Not sure why it's not changing the value to true even though the provider attribute is blank.

Comment: I'm checked this code in console, and it works. Try to run `rails c` and play with `toggle_pro?` and `provider.blank?`.

Comment: Could it be because I have :pro in attr_accessible ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14834/discussion-between-denis-peplin-and-crazycodermonkey)

Answer (score 1):

```
def toggle_pro
  self.pro = !self.pro if provider.blank?
  self.save!
end
```

Comment: Could it be that you have defined the method pro in you User class?
Also, I didn't understand what are you getting as a result to the method I wrote here - false? nil? error?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors just false in the database. pro is part of attr_accessible should i remove it?

Comment: I'm repeating my question - did you check that you did not redefine the pro method as in 
`def pro;
  #something;
end`

Comment: It is set as   def pro?
    provider.blank?
  end

Comment: Then I have your code below that. If I just use your code the user cannot access the pro section, it needs the pro method as well. The other parts of the code uses the pro method and its in too many places to change to toggle_pro

Comment: `code` def pro?
    self.pro = !self.pro if provider.blank?
    self.save!
  end  something like that lets me keep the pro method but still returns false

Answer (score 0):

Now you can simply toggle your boolean field using **[ActiveRecord#toggle](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle)** method

for eg:

```
@user.toggle!(:pro)
```

If your record is `false` then it will become `true` or visa versa. No need to make `save` / `update` call on your object if you have used `toggle!`.

**Note:** The method skips validations and callbacks. Attribute must be passed as a symbol.